# json file to add a title over the link

Tags: json

I am what most of you would call a noob.
I have this json and I want to add a title over the hyperlink

```
{
  "content": "test $POST",
  "originalContent": "[[{\"type\":\"text\",\"content\":\"text to write as content \"},
  {\"type\":\"link\",\"content\":{\"url\":\"https://example.com\"}}
  ]]", 
  
  "links": [], 
    "id": 1027,
    "slug": "clientfile",
    "symbol": "POST"
  }]
}
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: this is a json file,

Comment: my friend has a react website and he wants a title over his https://example.com link but he is even worse then me at this.